# Writing csv to s3 bucket inconsistent error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker

> The unspecified location constraint is incompatible for the region
> specific endpoint this request was sent to

I need to write a lot of CSVs to an s3 bucket from a sagemaker notebook

I have the following code that I use.

```
def create_user_block(algo
                  ,user
                  ,items
                  , pathTo
                  , popularity=None):

log('Creation of user block for {} started'.format(user))

recomendations = []
for item in items:
    recomendations.append(algo.predict(uid=user, iid=item))

    
recomendations = pd.DataFrame(recomendations)['iid est'.split()]
recomendations['est'] = recomendations.est.round()
recomendations = recomendations[ recomendations.est >=4]


if popularity is not None:
    popularity.columns = 'iid Popularity'.split()
    recomendations = recomendations.merge(right=popularity, how='left', on='iid')
    recomendations = recomendations.sort_values(by='est Popularity'.split(), ascending = False)

else:
    recomendations = recomendations.sort_values(by='est', ascending = False)

log('User block for {} returned'.format(user))

recomendations.to_csv( pathTo+'user_'+user+'.csv', index=False)
```

The function creates a csv file from a model and then writes it to a specific location.

So far so good

That function is wrapped around a second function that simply increments and calculates a few global variables in order to track my progress

```
def create_user_block_progress(algo
                           , user
                           , items
                           , popularity
                           , pathTo =os.environ['UPCARS_RECOMMENDATION_LOCATION']):
global count, noUI, progress

try:
    create_user_block(algo=algo, user=user, items = items, pathTo=pathTo, popularity=popularity)

    count = count+1


    if progress < int(((count/noUI)*100)):
        progress = int(((count/noUI)*100))

        update_item(field = 'progress'
                , value = progress
                , tableName = os.environ['UPCARS_ACTIVE_TASK_TABLE']
                , key = os.environ['UPCARS_ACTIVE_TASK_KEY']
                , createdAt = os.environ['UPCARS_ACTIVE_TASK_CREATED_AT'])

except Exception as e:
    meta_log('FAILED to create user block for {} due to the following error: {}'.format(user, e), True)
```

and then I run the wrapper function on multiple threads as written below:

```
 with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        threads = [executor.submit(create_user_block_progress
                                    , algo
                                    , u
                                    , items
                                    , itemPopularity) for u in users]
```

The pathTo is an S3 bucket and up until yesterday there were no issues. As of the last two days I keep getting an occasional error. As in this error could or could not occur for the exact same user regardless. Sometimes it happens sometimes it does not. Sometimes it does not happen at all. Sometimes it happens all the time.

And when it does happen I get the following error:

> The unspecified location constraint is incompatible for the region
> specific endpoint this request was sent to

So far I am baffled at what the issue is. If anyone could help me please I would appreciated.

In effect the issue appears sometimes and I do not know why when I try to write a csv to an s3 bucket.

The command that gives the error is something like:

```
recomendations.to_csv( 's3://local-recommendations/m1/knn/v8/user_123567.csv', index=False)
```

And it is this command that gives an error sometimes but sometimes not. The inconsistency is maddening

Comment: If possible, you may format the exact error message or error stack here for others to have a better clue what happened.